# Async Task in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous

I tried to run a task for a WPF UI Code Behind . but it doesn't work and noting happend when I use  `Task.Factory` but it works when I use the code without `Task.Factory`

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    GetNews();
}

private void GetNews()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        FeedReader reader = new FeedReader();
        var news = reader.RetrieveFeed("http://www.bbc.com/feed/");
        foreach (var item in news)
        {
            textBlock.Text = item.Title;
        }
    });
}
```

How can I use async/await or anything that prevent block main thread?

Comment: Please update your question and explain what you mean when you say "it doesn't work". Does the code not run at all (verified with a debugger breakpoint)? Does it run but have no visible effect? Are exceptions being thrown? Is the application crashing? Also, what is the "textBlock" variable actually referencing?

Comment: @Xavier I edited my question. textBlock is a control in my xaml UI

Comment: But, you are setting in a loop the same control... so at the end its text will be the title of the last item.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten it's not important, I know

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing happens because an exception is thrown as you are trying to modify UI element outside of UI thread. You should either use `textBlock.Dispatcher.Invoke` method or make `FeedReader` asynchronous and use `async/await` in your method, which is preferable.

So the prefered solution would be (provided `RetrieveFeed` is async method):

```
private async void GetNews()
{
    FeedReader reader = new FeedReader();
    var news = await reader.RetrieveFeed("http://www.bbc.com/feed/");
    foreach (var item in news)
    {
        textBlock.Text = item.Title;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could wrap feed retrieval in a task, which will work with your current implementation:

```
private async void GetNews()
{
    FeedReader reader = new FeedReader();
    var news = await Task.Run(() => reader.RetrieveFeed("http://www.bbc.com/feed/"));
    foreach (var item in news)
    {
        textBlock.Text = item.Title;
    }
}
```

This approach will work because await will capture `SynchronizationContext` of UI thread and will set value to the textbox in UI thread.

And the caveat here is that exceptions thrown in `async void` method are never observed and are lost. So you should wrap the code inside `GetNews` method in `try/catch` block and at least log the exception so you are aware of it.

Comment: You don't show how to call an `async` method from the constructor.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, nothing changes there, the method is `async void`.

Comment: for first solution an error occurs: **'IEnumerable<FeedItem>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<FeedItem>' could be found**

Comment: @Mike yes, that's correct. I have added a note that the method should be changed to become asynchronous.

Comment: Something changes when the reader throws an exception. The `async void` will make that disappear without a sound. `async` and constructors is not an easy subject, worth googling a bit.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, very true, that's why I outlined that in my answer. The method is called from `ctor`. And there is no good way to call it in async way. Task.Wait will cause a deadlock. `AsyncPump` can be an option, but still blocking call.

Comment: Async void methods do not swallow exceptions; they raise them on the `SynchronizationContext` that was active at the beginning of the method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the async version to retrieve the feed

```
SyndicationFeed feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(uri).AsTask(ct);
DisplayResults(feed);
```

Check the [example from msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj631575(v=vs.110).aspx).

It calls the Windows Runtime method, `RetrieveFeedAsync`, and applies a .NET Framework extension method, `AsTask`, to the returned `IAsyncOperation` instance. `AsTask` represents the instance as a Task, so that you can await it.